# Alter Column Contents 

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MYSQL database I wish to edit. In the database under the table `sites` in the column `spider_depth` I want to change the content from 2 to 0.

For example

```
Spider_depth | 2
```

to

```
Spider_depth | 0
```

Instead of editing 1000+ entires in the DB

Comment: The statement is called `UPDATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE sites
SET Spider_depth = 0
WHERE Spider_depth = 2
```